# Can I say, "Bless You" to our Catholic priest?

Tags: catholicism, blessings, priests

Our priest does such a great job at our church. I shook his hand after church and said "Bless you".  I meant to say "Bless you for all you do", but was it offensive to bless a priest?

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: Try asking him, and then posting what he said as the answer here.

Answer (score 5):

"Bless you!" is short for "[May God] bless you!"
So, you are not blessing a priest, but asking God to.

Comment: Where's your evidence that any time anyone ever says "bless you" this is what they mean?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you did is rather good. Even pope Francis 1st, just elected, [asked everybody to bless him](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/speeches/2013/march/documents/papa-francesco_20130313_benedizione-urbi-et-orbi.html):

> And now I would like to give the blessing, but first - first I ask a
>   favour of you: before the Bishop blesses his people, I ask you to pray
>   to the Lord that he will bless me: the prayer of the people asking the
>   blessing for their Bishop. Let us make, in silence, this prayer: your
>   prayer over me.